# Read-only file system RHEL

Tags: linux, filesystems, read-only, mount, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am using a RHEL 5.5 on my PC. I was playing around with chmod and chown. suddenly my home folder become read-only. all the folders in /home/goutham/, where goutham is username, became read-only. I can delete files after turning on system for few seconds, after that it says Permission denied:read only file system. I cant even create folder with sudo mkdir also. Please help me. My os is on /dev/sda3

Comment: can't you just add wx to you home directory using chmod?

Comment: I did that, but it doesn't work. it says "chmod: changing file system permissions: Read only file system"

Comment: What is the output of the mount command?

Comment: did you mess with the mount?

Comment: Yeah, I tried mount -o remount /home/goutham It dint give any output, but doesn't work.

Comment: Have you also tried 'mount -o rw,remount /home/goutham'?

Comment: @Abrixas2 It says /dev/sda3 is write-protected. mounting read-only.

Comment: Um, that's strange... actually, hdparm allows setting the 'read-only' flag on a drive, but that should then affect the whole drive, not just a single partition...

Comment: The kernel remounts a filesystem readonly if there's something wrong with it. Check dmesg and the logs in /var/logs and see what's up. Also, boot with a live system and run a fsck on /dev/sda3.

Answer (score 1):

My problem is Solved after running the command `e2fsck -C -p -f -y /dev/sda3` 
Thanks for everyone.